# Calculating t-statistics in event studies

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I am conducting an event study in STATA based on this description: http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/stats_packages/stata/eventstudy.html

I reached the point when I need to calculate t-statistics to be able to test whether cumulative abnormal return for event window is statistically significant from 0.

And now follows the problem. By analyzing the code above, I see that authors calculated abnormal returns only for the event window (i.e. for 5 days). Based on this data they calculated standard deviation of AR (again, sample size 5 days). And later used sd to calculate t-statistics.

But:

1. If they have such a small sample size why they suggest to use Z-scores rather than t-table: " If the absolute value of test is greater than 1.96, then the average abnormal return for that stock is significantly different from zero at the 5% level". is it a mistake, or am I missing smth?
2. What to do if I want to look at event window of only 1 day? In this case it is not possible to calculate sd at all, because we have sample size of 1. Why authors calculate sd only based on value of AR from event window, and not from estimation window for example?

Comment: The question primarily deals with doing statistical testing using STATA for multiple problems.

Comment: Michael, hi! I am not asking to explain the STATA code. Prinston description includes some theoretical info - my question is basically why they are calculating standard deviation of abnormal returns based on AR from event window (which is always pretty small) rather that from estinmation window e.g.? Is it a mistake or I am missing smth?

Comment: Hi! Firstly doing an event study with one or two days or n number of days doesnot matter for standard errors untile you have a sufficient number of observations to calculate the respective coefficients to estiamte the effect of the event. So 1 day doesnot mean sample size of 1 if you ahve say millions of firms or units around the event to calcualte the effect. Hope this helps